# Spark aggregateByKey reduceByKey - aggregation (e.g collection) must be thread safe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, thread-safety

This probably sounds basic. If I do aggregateByKey or reduceByKey, and I aggregate a specific implementation of a collection. Do I need to use a thread safe collection during this aggregation ?
Is this OK ?

```
val sc: SparkContext = ???
val notAggregated = Seq(((1), 100),((1), 200),((1), 300),((2), 100),((2), 200))
sc.parallelize(notAggregated)
  .aggregateByKey(mutable.HashSet.empty[Int])(
    seqOp = (set, member) => set += member,
    combOp = (set1, set2) => set1 ++= set2)
  .foreach(println(_))
```

Answer (score 1):

It don't have to be thread safe.

It uses combineByKey in the background and, if you look at Spark source code, class [PairDStreamFunctions.groupByKeyAndWindow](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/PairDStreamFunctions.scala#L71). It uses ArrayBuffer as a combiner. Look also [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala#L165) in the comment, it says why it's thread-safe

Why?

You are not putting zero value directly - you write function that creates combiner. Then Spark creates combiner in each partition (clones the value for each partition). One combiner in one partition is used like normal object, without parallel access from many threads in application as objects in one partition are processed sequentially